# Asp.net Search For Special Chars with HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, character-encoding, urlencode

I'am using this codes for search.

```
Response.Redirect("/Search/" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtAra.Text));
```

Decoding parameter with

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["tag"])
```

For example I write "Ahşap" textbox and redirecting.
Then on search page  `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["tag"])`

returns like "ahÅap" 
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You must do url encode, and then the query string is automatically decode it. (the html encode is not for the url)

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with this way.

[Decrypt and Encrypt](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-QueryString-Parameter-Values-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)